# VPS CentOS MySQL with authentication_string is NULL for all databases

Tags: mysql

I have a VPS CentOS 6.9, when I login via ssh with my user and then sudo su to root and type mysql, I get direct access to mysql with no authentication access prompted. When I load the list of all users `SELECT host, user, authentication_string FROM mysql.user;` I see that all of them have authentication_string set NULL.

Is it normal that root has no authentication_string and all users have authentication_string set to NULL?

Every time I create a DB, it is from cPanel and I create a user with password which I associate to it in order to connect to that DB from PHP scripts. Is there a security issue in my MySQL on my server or is it normal?

NB: If I add password to the MySQL query SELECT host, user, authentication_string, password FROM mysql.user; I see the below picture:
[image]

[image]Thanks.

Comment: An empty string (`''`) is not the same as `NULL`. Whatever.. What's the MySQL version? What do the `Password` and `Plugin` columns have?

Comment: Server version: 5.6.38 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)                                  Some of the users have in password  *059F8F.........70.AB8..... and in plugin mysql_native_password some others have empty value in plugin

Comment: What does the following query return?: `SELECT \`plugin\` FROM \`mysql\`.\`user\` WHERE \`User\` = 'root';`. Check [6.5.1.8 Socket Peer-Credential Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html).

Comment: it returns 4 times  mysql_native_password